# Screen flickering after enabled Nvidia Graphics on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, 15.04, graphics, display

I enabled and installed Nvidia Graphics on my system but after I rebooted my system keeps flickering on Unity, Compiz and Metacity but not on tty.

My Nivdia graphic card is a GT 650m.

How do I disable or fix the flashing of my screen?

Details: I have any access from desktop graphical interface just try.

Comment: How did you install the driver?

Comment: What's your system?  Is it a laptop hybrid Intel/Nvidia graphics?

Comment: And which version did you install? from nvidia website or the apt-get?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I followed exactly this tutorial http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: @ubfan1 It is a Dell Inspiron 17r 7720. I think it is. There is both Nvidia graphic card and Intel Ivy Bridge I suppose. It is x64 bit Ubuntu.

Comment: @Saeid87 I installed via apt and the version that I took from Nvidia site is 352.63.

Comment: try "nvidia-current" instead....its more stable in my book!

Comment: @Saeid87 I remember I did this install via apt but I can reassure.

Comment: @Saeid87 Yes it is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a fundamental problem with synchronization of the Intel and Nvidia video components in (certain?) laptops.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tearing  for many proposed solution to the issue.
  Also, the xorg-edgers ppa has an alternative, sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa  which should be the latest drivers.